# bit32.band like operation in 64 bits

Tags: lua

I want to apply a bitwise AND operation in 64 bits in Lua 5.1. Is there an algorithm for it? (I have no idea on how to do it.)

**Note**: I only need to operate on 48 bits at total, and I am not having trouble with them.

In the game's Lua I'm scripting there's the `bit32` library only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local function band48 (x, y)
   local xl = x % 4294967296
   local yl = y % 4294967296
   local xh = (x - xl) / 4294967296
   local yh = (y - yl) / 4294967296
   return bit32.band(xh, yh) * 4294967296 + bit32.band(xl, yl)
end

print(band48(7 * 2^33 + 3, 5*2^33 + 5)) --> 5*2^33+1 = 42949672961
```

Answer (score 1):

Lua is using double floating numbers internally by default. It has only 52 bits for mantissa, so you can't safely store 64-bit integers without risking to get invalid floating point values. 
With 32 bits it's quite safe. Lua 5.2 manuals describe what happens in bit32 lib with the numbers:

> Unless otherwise stated, all functions accept numeric arguments in the
>   range (-2^51,+2^51); each argument is normalized to the remainder of its
>   division by 2^32 and truncated to an integer (in some unspecified way),
>   so that its final value falls in the range [0,2^32 - 1]. Similarly, all
>   results are in the range [0,2^32 - 1].

You'll have to work in 32-bit chunks.
Or maybe introduce your own 64-bits type, probably hosted with userdata, and define 64-bit actions for that type.

Comment: Really thanks for the answer! I haven't got any help until your answer, and nor so far, but actually I only need to use 6 octet bytes from the number. This is basically because I want to create a byte array system, where each byte can be modified more dinamically, without using the Lua strings. Each number would be like 6 octet bytes. So yes, I have noticed that I would get into risk with 64 bits, but I haven't see any risks by using only 48 bits (6 octet bytes), and so I only really need to verify on these 6 bytes. I mostly wanted to do this to avoid wasting memory

Comment: You may also give a look at my code, but I stopped writting until I had no idea on how to do the AND op. algorithm. https://pastebin.com/MFijjRCK

Comment: You can't shift bits in mantissa with dividing number by 2. You will only get exponent field decremented. See how's floating point numbers working: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood that only the first 48 bits will be used for doing these things and shiftings. I always tried to understand these floating point/double precision encodings, but I don't :///... so mantissa is the integer number container, right? Then this way 48 bits will fit in 52 bits.

Comment: bit32 lib will cut those 52 bits down to 32 bits. And you can't shift bits in mantissa before that cutting. When you divide floating point by 2 you're not shifting mantissa at all, you're decrementing exponent field. If the bits you're interested in is not accessible within those cut 32 bits, you can't get them in that area by dividing or multiplying floating number on Lua side.