# Unexpected values from bit manipulations

Tags: lua

I'm trying to build a dynamic byte array class for Lua 5.1/5.2. It's a very limited Lua server platform in a Flash game, they allow me do nothing more beside executing a single source code.

Each byte is denoted by 8 bits inside a number that is inside a table of numbers.

I'm temporarily testing it by attempting to write a string (`'abc'`), pass its bytes to the byte array, but when checking the respective number of these bytes, its value is wrong. It should be `0x636261` (because `a` is `0x61`), but it results in `6300000` actually.

```
local arr = bytearray:new('abc', 5);
print(arr[LK_Stack][1]);
```

I use, at the maximum, 7 bytes from a stack number (56 bits). I got an adaptation bitwise AND function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43700128#43701240) answer for checking over 32 bits. I attempt to use the `bit32` library where possible.

This is temporarily how I implement my byte reading and writting functions that operate on a specific number from the stack of a byte array. The writting function must return the stack number back in changed state.

```
local Opr_readByte;
local Opr_writeByte;

if _16 then
    -- ...
else
    function Opr_readByte(n, bit)
        if bit == 48 then
            local add = band(n, 4) > 0xB;
            return floor(n / (add and 0x1000000000001 or 0x1000000000000));
        end
        if bit == 40 then return band(floor(n / 0x10000000000), 0xFF); end
        if bit == 32 then return band(floor(n / 0x100000000), 0xFF); end
        if bit == 24 then return band(floor(n / 0x100000000), 0xFF); end
        if bit == 16 then return band(rshift(n, 16), 0xFF); end
        if bit == 8 then  return band(rshift(n, 8), 0xFF); end
        return                   band(n, 0xFF);
    end

    function Opr_writeByte(n, bit, val)
        if bit == 48 then return (val * 0x1000000000000) + Opr_band56(n,   0xFFFFFFFFFFFF); end
        if bit == 40 then return (val * 0x10000000000)   + Opr_band56(n, 0xFF00FFFFFFFFFF); end
        if bit == 32 then return (val * 0x100000000)     + Opr_band56(n, 0xFFFF00FFFFFFFF); end
        if bit == 24 then return (val * 0x1000000)       + Opr_band56(n, 0xFFFFFF00FFFFFF); end
        if bit == 16 then return (val * 0x10000)         + Opr_band56(n, 0xFFFFFFFF00FFFF); end
        if bit == 8  then return (val * 0x100)           + Opr_band56(n, 0xFFFFFFFFFF00FF); end
        return                    val                    + Opr_band56(n, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF00);
    end
end
```

And this is my full current code.

```
do
    --[=[ pre-locals BEGIN ]=]

    local band         = bit32.band;
    local lshift       = bit32.lshift;
    local rshift       = bit32.rshift;
    local floor        = math.floor;
    local min          = math.min;
    local byte         = string.byte;
    local getmetatable = getmetatable;
    local setmetatable = setmetatable;
    local tonumber     = tonumber;
    local type         = type;

    local BIT5 = (0x7FFFFFFF + 1) == 0x7FFFFFFF and 16 or 48;
    local _16 = BIT5 == 16;
    local BYTE5 = _16 and 4 or 7;

    --[=[ pre-locals END ]=]

    --[=[ Tracker BEGIN ]=]

    --[=[
     * *****
     * Offset indices consist of [[number index]] and [[bit index]].
     * *****]=]

    local function Tracker_backward(x, y)
        if y <= 0 then return x - 1, BIT5 end
        return x, y - 8;
    end

    local function Tracker_forward(x, y)
        if y >= BIT5 then return x + 1, 0 end
        return x, y + 8;
    end

    local function Tracker_track(x, y, yx, yy)
        while y < x do yx, yy = Tracker_forward(yx, yy); y = y + 1; end
        while y > x do yx, yy = Tracker_backward(yx, yy); y = y - 1; end
        return yx, yy;
    end

    local function Tracker_optimalIndexFor(target, x, xx, xy, y, yx, yy)
        local zx = target > x and target - x or x - target;
        local zy = target > y and target - y or y - target;
        local optimal = min(zx, zy, target);
        if optimal == zx then return xx, xy; end
        if optimal == zy then return yx, yy; end
        return 1, 0;
    end

    --[=[ Tracker END ]=]

    --[=[ Opr BEGIN ]=]

    local Opr_readByte
        , Opr_writeByte;

    if _16 then
        function Opr_readByte(n, bit)
            if bit == 16 then return rshift(n, 16); end
            if bit == 8 then return band(rshift(n, 8), 0xFF); end
            return band(n, 0xFF);
        end

        function Opr_writeByte(n, bit, val)
            if bit == 16 then return lshift(val, 16) + band(n, 0xFFFF); end
            if bit == 8 then return lshift(val, 8) + band(n, 0xFF00FF); end
            return val + band(n, 0xFFFF00);
        end
    else
        local function Opr_band56(x, y)
            local xl = x % 0x10000000000;
            local yl = y % 0x10000000000;
            local xh = (x - xl) / 0x10000000000;
            local yh = (y - yl) / 0x10000000000;
            return band(xh, yh) * 0x10000000000 + band(xl, yl);
        end

        function Opr_readByte(n, bit)
            if bit == 48 then
                local add = band(n, 4) > 0xB;
                return floor(n / (add and 0x1000000000001 or 0x1000000000000));
            end
            if bit == 40 then return band(floor(n / 0x10000000000), 0xFF); end
            if bit == 32 then return band(floor(n / 0x100000000), 0xFF); end
            if bit == 24 then return band(floor(n / 0x100000000), 0xFF); end
            if bit == 16 then return band(rshift(n, 16), 0xFF); end
            if bit == 8 then  return band(rshift(n, 8), 0xFF); end
            return                   band(n, 0xFF);
        end

        function Opr_writeByte(n, bit, val)
            if bit == 48 then return (val * 0x1000000000000) + Opr_band56(n,   0xFFFFFFFFFFFF); end
            if bit == 40 then return (val * 0x10000000000)   + Opr_band56(n, 0xFF00FFFFFFFFFF); end
            if bit == 32 then return (val * 0x100000000)     + Opr_band56(n, 0xFFFF00FFFFFFFF); end
            if bit == 24 then return (val * 0x1000000)       + Opr_band56(n, 0xFFFFFF00FFFFFF); end
            if bit == 16 then return (val * 0x10000)         + Opr_band56(n, 0xFFFFFFFF00FFFF); end
            if bit == 8  then return (val * 0x100)           + Opr_band56(n, 0xFFFFFFFFFF00FF); end
            return                    val                    + Opr_band56(n, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF00);
        end
    end

    --[=[ Opr END ]=]

    local LK_Stack          = false;
    local LK_TrackX         = true;
    local LK_TrackXX        = 0;
    local LK_TrackXY        = 1;
    local LK_Length         = 2;
    local LK_Use_Le         = 3;
    local LK_OfsLength      = 4;

    local function resize(stack, x, y)
        if x < y then
            for i = x + 1, y do stack[i] = nil; end
            return;
        end
        for i = y + 1, x do stack[i] = 0; end
    end

    local t = {};

    do
        local metatable = {};
        local prototype = {};

        local function bytearray(_, arg, n)
            local stack = {};

            local arr = setmetatable({
                [ LK_Stack ] = stack,
                [ LK_TrackX ] = 1,
                [ LK_TrackXX] = 1,
                [ LK_TrackXY ] = 0,
                [ LK_Use_Le ] = true
            }, metatable);

            local _type = type(arg);
            local isNum = _type == 'number';
            local blen = not isNum and #arg;
            local len = tonumber(isNum and arg or (n or blen)) or 0;

            local ld = floor((len / BYTE5) + 1);

            arr[LK_Length] = len;
            resize(stack, ld, 0);

            arr[LK_OfsLength] = ld;

            if not isNum then
                blen = blen % (len + 1);
                if _type == 'string' then arg = { byte(arg, 1, blen) }; end

                local n, x, y = 0, 1, 0;

                for i = 1, blen do
                    n = Opr_writeByte(n, y, arg[i]);
                    local xsav = x;
                    x, y = Tracker_forward(x, y);
                    if x ~= xsav then stack[xsav] = n; n = 0; end
                end

                stack[x] = n;
            end
            return arr;
        end

        local prototype = {};

        function prototype:getlength()
            return self[LK_Length];
        end

        function prototype:setlength(len)
            resize(self[LK_Stack], len, self[LK_Length]);
            self[LK_Length] = len;
        end

        metatable.__index = prototype;
        t.new = bytearray;
    end

    bytearray = t;

    local arr = bytearray:new('abc', 5);
    print(arr[LK_Stack][1]);
end
```

Comment: I think this is more a question for your debugger than for SO. But from what you've said I see an issue, but it might not be your issue. Lua numbers are IEEE double-precision floating point values on most systems, they have a precision of 51 bits, but you are trying to store 56 bits in them. If at some point you store data in both the highest byte and lowest byte you are going to lose data in the lowest byte.

Comment: @ktb I think I'm not able to understand this double precision float point representation yet. but from my point of view, it's okay to use 56 bits in the platform I script Lua. I script Lua for a MMO game, where the Lua code is ran by server. There's no way to add low-level external libraries, thus I want to create a byte array class that tries to re-use bytes from numbers. I'm able to compare 56 bits with `band56` in general runtimes. I've not tested the game runtime yet, but I was able to represent numbers of 56 bits yet (unsigned integer).

Comment: What does this mean: `local add = band(n, 4) > 0xB` ?  `band(n,4)` is either `0` or `4`, so it is always less than `0xB`

Comment: Your `Opr_band56()` will work only with 52-bit numbers (51-bit maximum on some implementations).  It will NOT work with 56-bit numbers.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff 1) I've confused my self in this part... `4` should be haven been `0xF` (half octet-byte). 2) In the server Lua runtime from the game I'm gonna put this in action, `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` was printed (exactly 7 octets), and I've compared it against my browser's JavaScript runtime too. Do you think I can do it?

Comment: `print((0xFF * 0x1000000000000 + 0xFF) % (0xFF + 1))` Run that, it creates a number with the highest (byte 7) and lowest byte (byte 0) set to `0xFF`. Then it masks out the first byte. It should result in 255, but it returns 0 on my machine. If you limit the number of bits to 48 (6 bytes), it works as intended. But really the bit32 library exists, you might as well make everything 32 bits for simplicity.

Comment: Lua 5.3 added bit operators and 64-bit integers.

Comment: @ktb Hum, here it prints `0xFF` in https://lua.org/cgi-bin/demo (Lua 5.3 and 64 bits). Though that's not the Lua platform I'm going to run my code on. I really need to use all possible bits to avoid leaking memory.

Comment: See lhf's comment. Lua 5.3 has 64-bit integers, which is what is running on the demo site. Your Lua 5.2-based platform (probably) only has IEEE double-precision floats which only have 52 bits of precision for you to store information. Using less of the available precision of each number and increasing the length of the array doesn't not constitute as a leak, and unless your byte streams are going to be particularly massive you won't notice. Use less bits in each number and if you run into memory usage issues, then resort to tricks. This is a case of premature-optimization.

Comment: @ktb Really, the game's Lua can represent big numbers, but your example did result `0` in the game's Lua. I did know that Lua 5.3 supports 64-bits, but I can't switch to it in the game and can't also use external libs. :/ Maybe you're right at some points though. I'm not sure if I'll be able to understand this representation easily and I only know that general Lua runtimes can represent numbers in two different ways (integer and double), or I might be wrong.

Comment: @Matheus Pre-5.3, Lua only had one numeric type and, if it was available, it was a double. I think the thing to take away, at least from this comment convo, is that you should restrict to 48 bits of usage per number, as the function was defined in Egor's answer in the previous question. Then go from there to find your issue, if it hasn't been resolved.